# Is a blob storage cost of cassandra is the same as bigint storage cost for long variables?

Tags: types, cassandra, blob, long-integer, blobstorage

I need to store a "Long" Java variable.
The question is: whether the storage cost is the same both for store hex representation of "Long" variable to the blob and for store "Long" variable to the bigint?
Are there any performance pros or cons?

Answer (score 0):

I think `blob` fields have a length int as a prefix. So it has a small overhead.

BTW if you already know you need a long data type, why don't you stick with `bigint`?